# Custom Directive with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my html I have included my directive like this.

```
<login ng-show="!authService.authenticated"></login>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('XXXXX').directive("login", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            authenticated: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: "views/layouts/login.html",
        controller: function ($scope, AuthService) { 
            $scope.authService = AuthService;
            $scope.authService.authenticated = false;

            $scope.authService.authenticated = AuthService.isAuthenticated();

            $scope.login = function () {
                var username = angular.element.find("[name='username']"),
                    password = angular.element.find("[name='password']"),
                    results = null;                            

                username = $(username).val();                        
                password = $(password).val();                               
                results = AuthService.login(username, password);
                if (results.status != "failed"){
                    $scope.authService.authenticated = true;    
                }                
            }; 
            console.log($scope.authService.authenticated);     
        },
        link: function (scope) {
        }
    }
});
```

Login service and authentication is working fine through the AuthService but the issue is once a successful login is done I still can't hide the login html set. Please someone help me to sort this out.

Thanks.

Comment: You should put your console.log within the scope.login = function {} at the end of it. Also print out what results.status is as well. Are you sure it is going inside the if (results.status != "failed") ?

Comment: could you add code of `isAuthenticated` method?

Comment: Yere. It is going inside the results.status != "failed"

Comment: isAuthenticated: function () {
            var authenticated = false,
                userInfo;
            if ($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]) {
                userInfo = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]);
                if (userInfo){
                    authenticated = true;
                }
            }
            return authenticated;
        }

Comment: the directive scope does not know the controller scope, which is what `ng-show` is looking at.

Comment: Thanks. OK What Shall I do for this ?

Comment: simple fix is move ng-show into directive template

Comment: options that come to mind: 1) add the `isAuthenticed` flag to root scope 2) access the parent scope from the directive 3) put the ng-show on the root element of your template or 4) emit an event in the directive

Comment: @RuchiraChamara polluting `$rootScope` would be not be good way to do it..

Comment: Unless you need the `authenticated` variable in the scope for other reasons, you should follow @Jorg's advice and put the ng-show on the root element of your template

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope instead of $scope.authService

```
angular.module('XXXXX').directive("login", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        authenticated: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: "views/layouts/login.html",
    controller: function ($scope,$rootScope, AuthService) { 
        $rootScope.authService = AuthService;
        $rootScope.authService.authenticated = false;

        $rootScope.authService.authenticated = AuthService.isAuthenticated();

        $scope.login = function () {
            var username = angular.element.find("[name='username']"),
                password = angular.element.find("[name='password']"),
                results = null;                            

            username = $(username).val();                        
            password = $(password).val();                               
            results = AuthService.login(username, password);
            if (results.status != "failed"){
                $rootScope.authService.authenticated = true;    
            }                
        }; 
        console.log($rootScope.authService.authenticated);     
    },
    link: function (scope) {
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Even though it works, using `$rootScope` in this manner is a bad practice.

Comment: i think this will help full for verifying the user is authenticated in whole project by checking up of this rootscope value , further checking up  of  if the user is present or not verification should not be needed in any controller

Answer (score 0):

As you declared `authenticated` variable in isolated scope, you should modify that scope variable by passing it from the directive attribute, then you can easily play with `authenticated` variable inside directive controller, make `authenticated` true when user is authorized otherwise it would be false.

**Markup**

```
<login authenticated="authenticated" ng-show="!authenticated"></login>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('XXXXX').directive("login", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            authenticated: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: "views/layouts/login.html",
        controller: function ($scope, AuthService) { 
            $scope.authService = AuthService;
            $scope.authService.authenticated = false;

            $scope.authenticated = AuthService.isAuthenticated();

            $scope.login = function () {
                var username = angular.element.find("[name='username']"),
                    password = angular.element.find("[name='password']"),
                    results = null;                            

                username = $(username).val();                        
                password = $(password).val();                               
                results = AuthService.login(username, password);
                if (results.status != "failed"){
                    $scope.authenticated = true;    
                }                
            }; 
            console.log($scope.authenticated);     
        },
        link: function (scope) {
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ruchira Chamara does it helped?